# Is it possible to set Transfer-Encoding: chunked header in request?

Tags: javascript, request, transfer-encoding

I need to send a request with *"Transfer-Encoding: chunked"* header set. When I *try to call xhr.setRequestHeader("transfer-encoding", "chunked")*, Chrome throws the following error in console: *"Refused to set unsafe header "content-length"*.

There is a lot of information about sending chunked responses. Is it possible to send chunked request to server?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569223/http-post-using-xhr-with-chunked-transfer-encoding

Comment: I understand that I can't set this header manually. Is there any way to make browser set it and send chunked request?