# Sending Chunked HTTP request from Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789703/how-to-write-javascript-in-client-side-to-receive-and-parse-chunked-response-i) shows how to read a chunked response in Javascript, but I would like to *send* a chunked HTTP POST from Javascript.  The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) for XMLHttpRequest doesn't mention anything.  Does the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569223/http-post-using-xhr-with-chunked-transfer-encoding) mean that it's not possible due to browser restrictions on setting the header?

Comment: You could do this with simple polling on the client and making periodic POST(s). As long as your remote process does not serialize access then you should be fine. You could add a custom header to identify the sequence or task for server side correlations.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can with `XMLHttpRequest` - it's old and somewhat limited, it's really just a backwards compatibility hack for a long-gone IE ActiveX component.

However, at the bleeding edge (not in Firefox yet) you can with `fetch` and [`TransformStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TransformStream). This lets you [*send* a stream from JS](https://web.dev/fetch-upload-streaming/#writable-streams).

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this MDN page about [Transfer-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding). You can set the type to chunked.

You have to specify how long each chunk will be, but it allows you to send data in chunks.

Answer (score 1):

I think XMLHttpRequest is very old, I think the alternative is to use `Axios` which is a newer JavaScript package which helps to handle network requests. It is much more easier than `fetch` and `ajax` in JavaScript.